# How can I link with a TouchableOpacity in React Native expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying ti link a button to another page and here is my issue: The answer to this question is on expo BUT with the class component. And the answer without expo is with the class or function component. But can someone tell me how to do this in a function?

Here is my code:

```
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button2}
              onPress={this._handleOpenWithLinking}
            >
              <Text style={styles.text3}>PLUG & PlAY</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

```
_handleOpenWithLinking = () => {
  Linking.openURL("https://expo.dev");
};
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a snack for this : [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/dJ5JHO-zi)

probably you got something wrong in importation

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to npm install expo-linking .